# Pyramid + github + pip: install problems

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid, mako

I need to install a Pyramid project from a private repo from github.

The project has a structure something like this:

```
project_name
  project_name
    models/
    views/
    templates/
    __init__.py

  setup.py
```

I do a `git clone` and then do `pip install project_name` to install it from the local repo in a `virtualenv`.

Then I start the server with `pserve production.ini` and it starts without problems.

But, I get problems locating the mako templates...

I get the error:

```
TopLevelLookupException: Cant locate template for uri for `home.mak`
```

Also, I notice that inside the `site_packages` where my project is installed, ALL the files are copied except the `templates/` directory. Why is this happening?

In my `production.ini`, I have the directive...

```
mako.directories = my_project:templates
```

And inside my view functions, I am doing something like this:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer="home.mak")
def home_view(req):
    ...
```

Why am I getting this error?

**UPDATE**

When I manually copy the `templates` folder into the `env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/my_pproject/` -- everything works just fine.

Hence, my question is: why is the `templates` directory NOT getting copied when I install the package?

Comment: Problem solved: I was missing the `MANIFEST.in` file.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the `MANIFEST.in` file which is important when you need to add non python files to your install.